# The video doesn't play audio in android build in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I put a videoPlayer component in scene. the video clip is 360 video file and the audio output mood is direct.  it's playing well on game view and IOS device but Android device. so anyone can help me? i'm grateful.[screenshot of the video player Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Fo1.png)

Comment: What'd your Unity and Android version?

Comment: Direct mode is not supported yet in VideoPlayer, you have to use AudioSource to play the audio. I don't remember where I read this, you can try looking it up tho

Comment: @Programmer The Unity version is 2017.1.0f3, Android Studio version is 2.3.3 and the android sdk is 7.1

Comment: @NikaKasradze where the audio is going well on ios?

Comment: I know its not an solution but as Nika said I remember that you need AudioSource to play Audio for android, no matter what. You can convert your video's audio into an audio file and play it via AudioSource? They are different operating systems so it may work on IOS but that doesnt mean anything for Android.

Comment: @NikaKasradze thank you for saving my day with your comment. I extracted audio from video then set "Audio Output Mode" to none and then added a new component of Audio Source and added audio to it. Works fine now.